# Logout Apple account from application

Tags: ios, authentication, unity-game-engine

I am developing a unity game and I implemented GPGS authentication that gives an option to sign out the account once it's signed in. Also I implemented Apple authentication using [this](https://github.com/lupidan/apple-signin-unity) plugin, but it doesn't provide any option to sign out.

After some research I found out that apple actually doesn't provide any options to logout from an account on a single device at all.

For now there are 2 options:

- Revoke the authorisation using POST request to the https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token/revoke. The problem here is that it will logout from all of the devices that used this account to log-in to that game/application.
- Add flags to PlayerPrefs (just persistence). Here if the player chooses to sign out we set "SignOutFlag" key to 0. And when player signs in with different creds (or the same ones) we set it to 1. Basically a general flag logic.

I don't like both options. Are there any other options out there? (ChatGPT actually told the same)

What I am expecting is that after logout when I am asking for `getCredentialStateForUserID` is will return `Revoked`.

**Honourable mention:** I am weak in all that backend/server/POST stuff, my maximum is about using sdk or plugin, but if there is any elegant way to get around this situation I am open to research.

Answer (score 1):

From my gravedigging so far, I haven't found any logout options. [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple) talk a lot about authenticating and signing in a user. Signing-in is also documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple).
Moving forward, [a forum thread](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/issues/10) on github regarding signing out on the React Native Apple Authentication says they can't do it. User ajw-m got a reply from Apple Support regarding this and posted it [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/issues/10#issuecomment-600304964), saying: *This behavior is by design; Sign in with Apple provides the mechanism to authorize a user, with their Apple ID, for a particular application. To remove access to an application, the user must manually revoke their credentials via the following support page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426*

Reading about it more, it seems that the Apple API does not provide a log-out. Because of this, other plugins or frameworks obviously can't log you out of a session either. This might be a security measure as to not have malware that you accidentally (such as being tricked) installed on your device will log you out and allow the malicious attacker to take over your devices and account.

Then again, you can manually call their API using [revoke_tokens](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens) . This is as far as the API support goes.
Manual handling is done via Apple devices where you can see what app or service used your cloud AppleId account and forcefully log them out.

Comment: Finally I used flags tbh XD. They work and I didn't found any other workaround....I will use revoking tokens anyway, as apple [requires](https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app/) to give user an opportunity to delete their account. Thanks anyway. Actually I thought that there will be many answers and discussions to this question, because there is literally no information about logout in the internet...